# What are the rate limits that throw the "Rate Limit Exceeded" error during an upload?

Tags: google-drive-api

### Case

I have this server-to-server file upload implementation that uses Google Drive on the other end. All of a sudden I've been seeing this **intermittent error** called [Rate Limit Exceeded](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/handle-errors#403_rate_limit_exceeded) during scheduled file uploads.

### Refactor and test

I know the error can be handled by [batching the uploads](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/batch) and/or by doing [exponential backoff](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/handle-errors#exponential-backoff) based from official documentation. My concern is the actual rate limits so I did a test.

I restructured the code to make the uploads 1 file only for every 3 minutes.
**Didn't work!** - still getting the same errors and still happens intermittent.

### Questions

Are there official figures as to maximum rate limits? How many requests per hour? Something like size-to-period ratio or number-of-requests-to-period ratio would really help.

What are the actual rate limits that throw/trigger the "Rate Limit Exceeded" error during a file upload?

Answer (score 0):

You can check your current traffic usage from https://console.developers.google.com.

Some operations like **create** and **update** operations have additional internal limits that may be lower than your allowed QPS.

Depending on your use case, there are more specific things you can do (e.g. slow down on per-user operations, but compensate by doing more users in parallel to maximize throughput).

Also, the "**[403 Rate Limit Exceeded](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/handle-errors#403_rate_limit_exceeded)**" errors that you are seeing may be occurring due to the number of read/write requests that you are performing per user per sec in your application. Please consider trying the following steps to reduce the errors:

> - You may need to optimize your code by reducing the number of api calls made simultaneously per user/sec.
> - Batch the requests.